# WINAPI control "EDIT"-Textbox receives no user input

Tags: windows, winapi, textbox

I have a textbox that is not set to "read-only", so theoretically I should be able to write to it. It is activated with Edit_Enable(hwnd, true), Edit_SetReadOnly(hwnd, false) and SetFocus(hwnd). I can give the textbox focus by clicking on it and I can even see the caret blinking, but however, when I press any key the textbox receives no input. I can set its text with Edit_SetText(), but I cannot write anything manually to it.

I create this textbox with following code:

```
DWORD dwStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL /*| ES_OEMCONVERT*/ | ES_LEFT /*| ES_WANTRETURN */| WS_TABSTOP;
        HWND h = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT", (LPCWSTR)NULL, dwStyle, posX, posY, width, height, hParent, NULL, (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

Messages are handled in this function. It is called every frame.

```
bool PumpMessages()
{
    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory( &msg, sizeof(MSG) );

    bool bQuit = false;

    // Use PeekMessage() so we can use idle time to update the system. 
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        // Translate and dispatch the message
        TranslateMessage(&msg);

        // message bug workaround
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            bQuit = true;
        }

        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return bQuit;
}
```

And the message procedure looks like following:

```
   LRESULT CALLBACK Window::WndProcThunk(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
   {
   if (msg == WM_CHAR)
       Log("WM_CHAR");
    ...
   // Finally, if the message isn't consumed by the window or any registered listeners, let Windows do its thing.
    return msgConsumed ? 0 : DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
   }
```

The second strange thing happens here in the WndProcThunk message procedure. No WM_CHAR messages are logged. I think this is the reason that my TextBox doesn't do anything, because it needs WM_CHAR messages to react on user key presses. I have to find the reason why no WM_CHAR messages are sent, even though I use TranslateMessage() in my PumpMessages function. Any ideas?

Comment: Check whether you are getting the `WM_KEYDOWN` messages. Those are what `TranslateMessage` use as input.

Comment: @rodrigo I don't get WM_KEYDOWN messages in the WndProcThunk either. I am using DirectInput 8 in the same thread, too. Could this intefere winapi key handling?

Comment: Which window is `WndProcThunk` the window procedure for? You would expect `WM_CHAR` messages to go to the window with focus, which presumably is the edit control?

Comment: In the WNDCLASSEX structure I had to fill out lpfnWndProc with the WndProcThunk pointer to register my main window class (main window is parent window of textbox window). Until now I was able to receive messages from the children windows, except they were common controls like status bars/progress bars etc. Maybe it's the same issue here with textboxes. But I thought passing NULL as the second parameter to PeekMessage() would cause that all messages of all windows (including children windows) of the current thread are sent to WndProcThunk.

Comment: @Weekendlegend: Yes, I think that DirectInput is eating your keyboard messages... but I know little about DI, so I cannot give you details...

Comment: Tomorrow I will test it without DirectInput enabled. I'll update you here.

Comment: Key presses go to the window procedure of the window with focus. Try using Spy++ to see if the edit control is actually seeing the messages.

Answer (score 0):

`PeekMessage` returns `FALSE` if no messages are in the message queue, so your message loop will exit almost immediately. You need to either switch to using `GetMessage` or refactor the loop so that you are using your `bQuit` flag as a test rather than the return value of `PeekMessage`.

Comment: This doesn't matter because the function PumpMessages is called every frame. When it returned true once, the application will quit.

Comment: Oops, sorry I missed that detail!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by disabling the DirectInput API. DirectInput 8 was actually eating all WM_KEYDOWM messages, which resulted in no WM_CHAR messages being sent. But the textbox needs WM_CHAR messages to react to user input. This is a strange behaviour of the API. If anyone has ideas to fix this problem without disabling DirectInput, feel free to post it. But I will use GetAsyncKeyState() for keyboard input from now on.